# Silverstripe 3 / Tabset / Special Chars / Issue

Tags: tabs, special-characters, silverstripe

I'm extending SiteConfig and create a new Tabset. I can't get it to work properly ; when using special chars in tabnames, the  layout is mixed up.

I also tried it with _t('MyClass.MyMainTab','Public') and a german language-yml without success. (also no success with & Ouml ;)

> How can i use SpecialChars in tab names (Tabset - names)?

yml:

```
SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - MyClass
```

MyClass:

```
class MyClass extends DataExtension{

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields){

        $set = new TabSet(
            'ÖffentlicherBereich',  // PROBLEM !!!!!
                new Tab(
                    'Einstellungen',
                        new LiteralField('Bla', 'Blabla')
                ),
                new Tab(
                    'OtherTab',
                        new LiteralField('Blabla', 'Bla')
                ),
                new Tab(
                    'AnotherTab',
                        new LiteralField('Blabla', 'Bla')
                )
        );

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main.Main',  $set);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you try to do? From your code you add another Tabset INSIDE Root.Main.Main (the double "Main" sounds suspicious to me). Or do you want to add one BESIDE Main tab?

Comment: hi wmk! i added an image to my question to demonstrate what i do.

Comment: instead of Shop Zeiten i'd like to use 'Öffnungszeiten'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I'd try to use [->setTitle()](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.5/class-TabSet.html) to add the title containing Umlauts if
   the formfield ID has problems with umlauts.
2. add the tabset to the `Root` tab directly, as it should be on the same level as `Root.Main`
3. Use `Tabset::create()` instead instead of `new Tabset()` for daisy chaining (and possible use of Injector)

Modified, untested code:

```
$set = TabSet::create(
    'OpeningTimes',  // PROBLEM !!!!!
        Tab::create(
            'Einstellungen',
                new LiteralField('Bla', 'Blabla')
        ),
        Tab::create(
            'OtherTab',
                new LiteralField('Blabla', 'Bla')
        ),
        Tab::create(
            'AnotherTab',
                new LiteralField('Blabla', 'Bla')
        )
)->setTitle('Öffnungszeiten');

$fields->addFieldToTab('Root',  $set);
```

Comment: and again you saved my day! Thanks a lot! TabSet::create & setTitle works as it should. also in combination with language-yml.

Comment: in a prior version of ss3 there was a problem with tabs (in SiteConfig) added to Root when clicking save. It always jumped back to the first Tab. Somewhere on Github i saw that workaround using Root.Main.Main to prevent jumping. Seems that Problem is solved (here 3.4)